# Failed to import pre-trained YOLOv8 model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, yolov8

I hope you can help me solve this issue and get the code running. This is my first attempt at running neural network code.I found the code on Kaggle, and when I tried running it on my local Jupyter Notebook, I encountered an error.I hope to have a friend help me figure out where the problem is. I feel it might be an issue with downloading the model's weight file. It seems that after an initial error during a run, the incorrect weight information is stored in the cache. Upon subsequent runs, the incorrect weight information is used. This is just my speculation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEJnk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqSlX.png)

I hope to have a friend help me figure out where the problem is. I feel it might be an issue with downloading the model's weight file. It seems that after an initial error during a run, the incorrect weight information is stored in the cache. Upon subsequent runs, the incorrect weight information is used. This is just my speculation.

Comment: Please don't share textual data as an image, share it as text. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask what you mean? I don't quite understand.

Comment: You added an image to your question that contains only text. It's bad practice to do that, you should prefer putting the text contained in the image directly in the question. See why here: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7370153)